# Spring Security error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Filter

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, microservices

I am using java17 with spring boot 3.0.0 version in my application. I have done the following configuration for spring security in web application. I have migrated java11 to java17 and using spring boot version as 3 and after that getting those errors.

I migrated java11 to java 17 and using updated spring boot version and after that upgradation I got the below errors.

package com.book.config;

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired; import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean; import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration; import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity; import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity; import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity; import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@EnableWebSecurity @Configuration public class WebSecurityConfig { @Bean public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception { http .csrf().disable() .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated() .and().cors().disable() .httpBasic(); return http.build(); } }
```

Following are the gradle dependencies, we are using:

```
plugins { id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.1' id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0' id 'java' }

sourceCompatibility = '17'

dependencies { implementation ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator') implementation ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb") implementation ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web') implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:5.5.7' implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:5.5.7' implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:5.7.0' implementation 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb' }
```

Error description:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Filter at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) \~\[na:na\] at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3402) \~\[na:na\] at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2504) \~\[na:na\] at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:465) \~\[spring-core-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4\] ... 21 common frames omitted Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.Filter at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) \~\[na:na\] at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) \~\[na:na\] at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) \~\[na:na\] ... 25 common frames omitted

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Filter

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.Filter

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Filter

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.Filter'
```

I have tried to add javax-servlet dependency, that did not work. what is the issue and what can be update to fix the error?

Comment: javax package ===> jakarta

Comment: SpringBoot 3.x supports Jakarta-EE rather than Java-EE.  You need to change the code that is using the `javax.servlet.*` classes to use `jakarta.servlet.*` instead.

Comment: If you are using SpringBoot 3.x (Jakarta-EE) you also need to upgrade to Spring Framework 6.0.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I see @EnableWebSecurity internally calling WebSecurityConfiguration class, which has following package :org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
so how to change here javax .servlet.Filter to Jakarta?

Comment: Replace your SpringSecurity 5.x dependencies with 6.x

Comment: thanks updating springSecurity dependencies with 6.x worked but cors(), csrf(), httpBasic shows  "deprecated and marked for removal" for below method:

public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().cors().disable()
                .httpBasic();

Comment: So rewrite the code that uses the deprecated methods.  Start by reading the deprecation notices (in the javadocs) to see if they suggest alternatives.

Comment: This change will require you to rename all javax.* imports to jakarta.* imports. https://howtodoinjava.com/java/whats-new-spring-6-spring-boot-3/